# Azure Pipeline error "Windows PowerShell is in NonInteractive mode. Read and Prompt functionality is not available."

Tags: azure-devops, powershell-4.0

I am trying to create CI/CD pipeline in azure databricks with azure devops using a windows self hosted agent. I am following this blog: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/ci-cd-azure-databricks-using-devops-deepak-rajak I am getting this error and I am not able to resolve it any idea how can I resolve this?

[image: Error]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [you're hitting a known issue](https://github.com/DataThirstLtd/databricks.vsts.tools/issues/23). Make sure the most recent version of the Azure CLI ir installed and available on the `%path%` for the user that runs the Azure Pipelines agent.